# Do medikits repair armor?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If your soldier takes more damage than he has bonus health from armor, his health will start depleting, resulting in him spending days in the infirmary. Does healing a soldier restore his armor's ability to block damage to health?

An exmaple: a soldier wearing Titan armor (10 bonus health) takes 8 points of damage. He is then healed by a medkit for 8 points of health. The soldier takes 6 points of damage. Has he taken health damage and thus requires time to recuperate, or has his armor absorbed 6 points of damage and he remains unharmed?

Comment: There is no distinction between "armor" and "health," is there?  Armors just give your character more health.

Comment: Nevermind, it [appears I'm wrong](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87298/2578).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they most certainly do. My support officer, Carrie Wagner, was wearing Titan armor (10 bonus health) and received 10 damage, which she healed with a medikit. She then took 10 more damage (It really is quite extraordinary she should get damaged for exactly her armor's bonus twice in a row, I couldn't hope for a better experiment) and at the end of the mission her status was active, not wounded.

Answer (score -1):

When you put on the armor you get the health bonus.
all damage taken goes to heath damage.
Healing restores 6 points of damage If I remember.
To avoid having soldiers out of action. just make sure they heal fully before completing missions.
This will either keep them in the fight or at least limit their recovery time.

Comment: Healing injuries in the field does absolutely nothing to shorten recovery time.