# What is the range of a medikit?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

What is the range of a medikit?

Does the medic have to be right next to the wounded soldier? Or can I heal them from one tile away? The circle graphic around the wounded soldier is ambiguous.

I'm playing an Ironman game right now and cannot experiment with saved games.

Comment: The circle graphic is exact

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness How can the circle be exact when the game is tile-based? Tiles are square. :-) The circle graphic fully overlaps some tiles and only partly overlaps some others. I can't make sense of it, or I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: If the center of the tile is inside the circle, the tile is in range, if it isn't - it's not.

Comment: Good question, I wanted to ask a similar one about the Arc Thrower...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the center of the tile is inside the circle, the tile is in range, if it isn't - it's not. This translates into the following:

[image: Medkit radius]

The area depicted is 5x5 tiles. Black is the injured operative, green are tiles from which healing is possible, red are the tiles from which healing is not possible.

Fun fact: [medkits repair armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/88765/do-medikits-repair-armor), so if you "heal" armor damage on an operative before the enemy gets through his armor, he won't have to recuperate no matter how many times armor hitpoints are removed.

Comment: I would also like to add that there is a dot overlaid on top of the currently highlighted tile. If the dot is within the circle graphic that indicates medkit/arc thrower range, you're safe. (I only noticed this after asking my question.)

Answer (score 1):

The above image is incorrect. It seems that dying units may fall to a side, causing the center of the unit to NOT be the center of the square it's in. The circle around the unit will thus be slightly displaced, and squares that are two squares away may or may not be within range.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or diagram showing this? It would help highlight exactly what's going on and where you should move your support guy when you have a critically-injured operative who slumped off to the side. (On a tangent, this is a pretty new answer; are you using Enemy Within, and does it make a difference?)